# Matplotlib - Glyph 8722 missing from current font despite being in font_manager

Tags: python, matplotlib

To check all available matplotlib fonts, I followed the instructions here:

http://jonathansoma.com/lede/data-studio/matplotlib/list-all-fonts-available-in-matplotlib-plus-samples/

"Phetsarath OT" is on the resulting list:

[image]

When I try `plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Phetsarath OT"` the plot generated contains the correct Phetsarath OT font, but an error message is triggered:

```
/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:211: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 8722 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=flags)
/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py:180: RuntimeWarning: Glyph 8722 missing from current font.
  font.set_text(s, 0, flags=flags)
```

Is there anyway I can suppress this error?

Answer (score 12):

Try this :

```py
    plt.rc('axes', unicode_minus=False)
```

Comment: This worked for me, only I had to do   plt.rcParams.update({'axes.unicode_minus' : False})

Answer (score -1):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-fonts-currently-available-for-matplotlib

Mr. Rishikesh Kumar Rishi authored the above website in which he wrote the following code which will print out a list of available fonts.
from matplotlib

```
import font_manager
print("List of all fonts currently available in the matplotlib:")
print(*font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf'), sep="")
```

When I print out the list of fonts and try to use them, I also often get missing glyphs messages.  Finding matplotlib friendly plots is quite difficult.  I am just adding Rishi's way of finding installed fonts, but acknowledging that it does not solve the missing glyphs issues.

```
UserWarning: Glyph 82 (R) missing from current font.
```

I will be following to see if anyone has a guide to Matplotlib friendly fonts!

Comment: How does this answer the original poster's question? It looks like this is a new question of yours.

Comment: This is adding information from another source.  As I have stated in my response, it does not solve the issue.  However, it does provide MORE information for anyone who searched on this question as to how to get the available fonts from the font_manager.  The information in the documentation is sparse.  If I wouldn't have already found Mr. Rishi's article, I would want to find it here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34399846)